# Hibernate commit after each transation makes it slow

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi i have an application in which a when request comes with an array i have to select data from the table and if not found generate new value and insert into the table,and then again the loops stats over check for the next value and so on. This will be done around 50000 times for a new request.

i am using

```
  public void save(Object obj,Session session)  {       

        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(obj);
            //session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
            //session.flush();

            session.clear();
            tx.commit();
        }
        catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);            

            if(tx!=null){
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } 
}
```

method to commit and it is called for each new value generated.like for each request it is called 50000 times.
I have to commit my transactions for each value cause i dont want a duplicate value to be generated in the table,so if a new request comes with the same data and the previous is running , the value should be fetched from the table. so i think i will have to commit each transaction.. But if i use classic JDBC and not hibernate this becomes quite fast y so? am i doing something wrong of is hibernate slow as compared to it? cause i think most of the time is consumed in begin and commit transaction again and again.

Comment: My understanding of this is fairly limited, but opening 50000 new sessions for every request is almost never what you want to do. I recommend instead saving all the values as a batch. If you're worried about duplicates, a hashmap may be able to solve that problem but it's quite hard to guess without more information about your situation.

Comment: but the session is opened just once. the begin and commit is called around 50000 times.

Comment: OK, but why are you saving each item individually?

Comment: and i cant use batch, cause of the problem i have mentioned if another thread comes in and am also using Identity so batch is disabled for that

Comment: cause is a new thread comes in with the same value request and the value is not saved in the table, a new value will get generated

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is *batch processing*.

Few ideas

- make transaction bigger (span more than 1insert)
- use optimistic locking: retry if conflicts occurred
- configure the JDBC batch size

To avoid duplicate insert, add an extra column that holds the *natural key* and has a unique constraint.

Comment: and i cant use batch, cause of the problem i have mentioned if another thread comes in and am also using Identity so batch is disabled for that

Comment: See updated answer. What is your natural key to identify entries?